# PHP: Malware Warning from Server When Creating File Paths

Tags: php, image, path, malware

I'm having a problem with malware warnings from hosting accounts
because when their servers see any PHP code like below resulting
in a variable that is a path '/images/bars/value10.gif' for example.
I have confirmed that only this path example is causing the malware
warning. With Godaddy servers they actually kill/delete the file as
soon as it's uploaded via FTP! Other hosting accounts like BlueHost
just give a malware warning.

On one of the servers I used for testing, even Google sent me an email
saying that they detected malware on the domain!!

So my question is: have you ever seen this before, and if so, what can
I change in my code so that I can create a file path like below WITHOUT
causing a malware indication?

The code below is a very small portion of a script I wrote which creates 
over 50 different image paths for a template showing bar graphs. This example
creates ONE bar value in the form of a GIF file.

```
$random_value = 823;

$lower_value = 800;
$upper_value = 850; 

if (($random_value >= $lower_value) && ($num <= $upper_value)) {

$value_bar = '/images/bars/value10.gif';

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's because of file path and not file itself?

Comment: Will test that @Mikk - thank for suggestion - will post results. OK - tested this by removing the images directories and files all together. Still gets removed from server as malware - so it must be the use the path ''/images/bars/value10.gif'

Comment: Try to remove chunks of the file until the alert is no longer being triggered.

Comment: Thanks @Melvin Kicchi - I did exactly as you suggested. As soon as I deleted ALL paths (e.g. '/images/bars/value10.gif';) from the file it worked. All malware warning went away. But I need to have these path variables for the script to work. I'm new at this so there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Can you try to figure out which path in particular triggers the malware warning?

Comment: This whole question is defunct now because it had nothing to do with the image paths. It had EVERYTHING to do with this code: fopen('http://www.mydomain.com/dir/file.php', 'r');